# AC to DC Filter Confirmation

Tags: dc, ac, diagram

[image: Schematic]

Of the circuit I need to know the name of and what it is; my guess is, is it an AC to DC current converter? Is anyone able to confirm or deny?

What does it act as when its all formed together? (Once again my assumption is up there.)

Comment: Depends on what the AC source is.

Answer (score 6):

The circuit on the left can be called an "AC power transformer and bridge rectifier with load resistor". If you added the capacitor from the circuit on the right you could call it "AC power transformer and bridge rectifier with load resistor and smoothing capacitor". Here's what the circuit with the smoothing capacitor does: -

[image]

And in more detail (but still a simplification for moderate load resistor values): -

[image]

Comment: But is it a smoothing Capacitor?
I just thought it was a Polarized Capacitor

Comment: It is a polarized capacitor in your circuit but the job it's doing is "smoothing" the output voltage from the bridge rectifier. You asked to know the name of the circuit not a description of the capacitor type.

Comment: @user36273 Here's a geeky way to think of it: Elves and humans are *races* (*types*) you can play in a game. Archer and warrior are *classes* (*roles*). In electronics, the **role** of the capacitor is *smoothing* but its **type** is polarized (probably electrolytic). Not all races are appropriate for all classes, for example, an elf might be a better archer than a warrior. Thus, another polarized capacitor, a tantulum, might not be appropriate for the *smoothing* role in this circuit.

Comment: @JYelton you need to be writing books or video games LOL